# MySQL Transaction with rollback upon @@error

Tags: mysql, transaction, rollback

I have done several transactions with MySQL but mainly using php's libraries as the handle. Using php you would have something as:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$pdo->execute('
    query1;
    query2;
    query3;
    query4;
');
if (exception)
    $pdo->rollback();
else
    $pdo->commit();
```

At this moment I know that the transaction will rollback because PDO is expecting an error from MySQL that will trigger the command to rollback the transaction.

Is there anyway with mysql to do something as:

```
begin transaction;
query1;
if SQLEXCEPTION
    rollback and exit;
query2;
if SQLEXCEPTION
    rollback and exit;
query3;
if SQLEXCEPTION
    rollback and exit;
query4;
if SQLEXCEPTION
    rollback and exit;
commit;
```

The idea would be to avoid continuing execution of the query if an error has been detected.

When we are dealing with a batch of 5 queries that might be ok to run through all but when dealing with a batch of 200 of them, that is a cost that I would prefer to be avoided.

I heard that there are other databases capable of doing this so can MySQL perform such task and how that would be done ?

Comment: Are you looking to only rollback the query that failed and have the transaction move on to the next query? Or does an error on _any_ of the queries roll back the whole transaction?

Comment: The idea is to rollback the whole transaction and avoid multiple trips to the database. It seems that the PDO lib is not capable of this and MySQL doesnt have a lot of support for a more advanced query style